# Could you provide some easy examples for positive mean curvature surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I want to see some examples on positive mean curvature surfaces (not necessary constant mean curvature). I can't find a source for this. Could you provide some examples (It would be better with calculations). Thank you.

Comment: Any convex surface. A saddle surface, where one direction is more curved than the other. Actually, since you can always make nonzero mean curvature be positive by flipping the normal if necessary, almost any surface has points of positive mean curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphere, or some quadric in $\mathbb{R}^3$, e.g. $\{(x,y,z)\ |\ z=x^2+y^2 \}$. But in general, you can check any Surface text book